# Добавление нескольких значений к событию onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать, чтобы при прике на div с классом "text", добавляло/удаляло значение в событие "onclick" для кнопки "button". Пытаюсь сделать выбор товаров, с добавление в корзину одной кнопкой.

```
<div class="text">cart.add('1');</div>
<div class="text">cart.add('2');</div>
<div class="text">cart.add('3');</div>

<button type="button" onclick="cart.add('1');cart.add('2');cart.add('3');">Add to Cart</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

так попробуйте, с удалением из массива при повторном клике

```js
var cart = { addOrRemove: function (e) { 
      if (!selectedDivs.includes(this.textContent)) {
        selectedDivs.push(this.textContent); 
        console.log("added " + this.textContent); 
       } else {
        selectedDivs.splice(selectedDivs.indexOf(this.textContent), 1);
        console.log("removed " + this.textContent); 
       }
    }
};

let items = document.getElementsByClassName("text");

[...items].forEach(item => item.addEventListener("click", cart.addOrRemove.bind(item)));

let selectedDivs = [];

function printSelected(){
  console.log(selectedDivs);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">cart.add('1');</div>
<div class="text">cart.add('2');</div>
<div class="text">cart.add('3');</div>

<button type="button" onclick="printSelected()">Add to Cart</button>
```

Comment: Что то не особо понятно, можно рабочий пример?)

Comment: Пример как раз таки рабочий

Comment: Вопрос: А как реализовать удаление при повторном клике?)